Why pm2 logs are being saved with root as owner?
I can perform all the pm2 commands with normal user, but to pm2 flush logs I need super user permissions.
I don't understand because the logs are being created at my home folder, but they have root ownership
$ ll /home/jfolpf/.pm2/logs/<myapp>-out-18.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6252 Jun  7 19:54 /home/<my_username>/.pm2/logs/<myapp>-out-18.log

How can I pm2 flush logs without sudo?
